# SLXNA plus Accelerometer causing screen to rotate during gamplay, solutions?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, rotation

SLXNA plus the acclerometer are a bad combination on WP7. I cannot lock down either landscape left or right so the screen will rotate. I tried to counter this using a rendertarget2d but this didn't work one hundred percent because the click regions of the buttons are still flipped 180 degrees.

Any ideas?
Thanks
-ZS

Comment: Just looked at this Q again.  Just to see things straight, are you saying you want to LOCK the device into LandscapeLeft / Landscape right so that it doesn't flip when you rotate the device?  The rotation / input is handled automatically by the framework as far as I understood.  Just threw a test app together and everything works as far as I can tell.

Comment: No I had wanted to lock the device into LandscapeLeft only. As far as I know this is not supported as I found out later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now it seems that this is a missing feature/bug with the SLXNA platform. There is no way to force the screen to be a specific landscape orientation. It will continue to flip between OrientationLeft and OrientationRight. There are several workarounds to this problem that I have devised, but none of them are ideal and all of them have their limitations. The best that I have found so far is to override the following function

```
protected virtual void OnOrientationChanged(
OrientationChangedEventArgs e
)
```

in the Microsoft.Phone.Controls namespace. Then have a variable inside to keep track of the orientation changes. Then instead of rendering directly to a SpriteBatch render to a [Rendertarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx) and then rotate it according to the variable you just modified. Now there is a drawback to this method and it is a big one: any touch controls do not flip. So you'll have a bunch of weird errors with the touch controls and buttons not lining up, but as of the moment this appears to be the best workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Default page Orientation in the silverlight XAML as with SilverXNA (SLXNA) the Silverlight page is the host for all 3D content and XNA does not have control over it.

Find this line in the header of your Page XAML (check for each page)

```
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
```

Values can be:

- Portrait
- Landscape
- PortraitOrLandscape

Also if you want to read the current page orientation you will need to translate the Silverlight Orientation to an XNA orientation.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Silverlight you cannot specify LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight. I ended up just counter-rotating the screen in order to get it to stay the same way, which is a pretty awful solution.